# Calculate new column in pandas using conditional on other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
pd.DataFrame({'A': [5, 2, -3],
   ...:       'B': [9, -1, 7],
   ...:       'C': [-5, 2, -6]})
Out[28]: 
   A  B  C
0  5  9 -5
1  2 -1  2
2 -3  7 -6
```

I would like to do the following

x > 0 -> (1+x)

x < 0 -> (1-x)^-1 (to the power of -1)

and then sum up all the columns.

resulting dataframe should look like this

```
   A  B  C   D        Logic
0  5  9 -5  16.1667   (1+5)+(1+9)+((1-(-5))^-1)
1  2 -1  2  6.5       (1+2)+((1-(-1))^-1)+(1+2)
2 -3  7 -6  8.3929    ((1-(-3)^-1)+(1+7)+((1-(-6))^-1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go with `np.where`:

```
df['D'] = np.where(df>0, 1+df, 1/(1-df)).sum(1)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C          D
0  5  9 -5  16.166667
1  2 -1  2   6.500000
2 -3  7 -6   8.392857
```